# Match 2 cells on different sheets and return a third

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel

Forgive me for posting a question that has been asked many times, but I have waded through every answer I can find and no luck.

I have 2 sheets (1 & 2)
I wish to compare Sheet 2 B3:B71 (Dates) with Sheet 1 J7:J44 (Dates) and when a matching date is found, print into the cell containing this formula, the corresponding contents of Sheet 2 C3:C71 (Currency).
Everything I try does not work out and I am tearing my already depleted hair out.

Can anyone help me?

I am using Excel 2016

I need to mention that I have only a simple understanding of excel as I am still on a very long learning curve.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where will the formula go, in Sheet1,K7 and the following cells?  If so, type this formula in K7 and fill down: `=VLOOKUP(J7,Sheet2!B$3:C$71,2,FALSE)`

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Bandersnatch's comment, you might get a #N/A returned on some cells if there is no match. You can replace that with something else by adding the following to the above formula.

`=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(J7,Sheet2!B$3:C$71,2,FALSE)),0,VLOOKUP(J7,Sheet2!B$3:C$71,2,FALSE))`

Just replace the '0' with anything else you want it to display.

Comment: Sorry I haven't explained correctly, Forgive my newbieness.
I have 2 sheets 2018 & Income.
On 2018 I have dates in J7:J44 and letters in the next cell K7:K44.
On Income I have dates in B3:B71 and Cost in C3:C71.
If a date from 2018 has the letter L (Upper or Lower Case) in the cell next to it K7:K44, Then I need The same date found in Income B3:B71 and The cost in Income C3:C71 printed in Income D3:D71.
Hope this makes some sense.
Thanks again